# how to serialize WifiConfiguration Object

Tags: android, serialization, wifi

i have a list of WifiConfiguration objects i want to serialize it iam using this code

```
 WifiManager volumeControl =(WifiManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 List<WifiConfiguration> info = volumeControl.getConfiguredNetworks();
 WifiConfigSerializable WifiInfo = new WifiConfigSerializable(info.get(0));
 serialize(WifiInfo.wifiList);

public void serialize(Object objToSerialize) {
            ObjectOutputStream out = null;
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(SETTINGS_FILE_NAME));

            out.writeObject(objToSerialize);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and the Serializable Class

```
public class WifiConfigSerializable extends WifiConfiguration implements Serializable{

    WifiConfiguration wifiList ;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public  WifiConfigSerializable( WifiConfiguration Wifi) {
        this.wifiList =  Wifi;
    }
  }
```

iam getting the following exception `java.io.NotSerializableException: android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration` how can i serialize the `WifiConfiguration` object.
any one can help?